# Usage of jquery map function for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I have this table:

```
    <table id="tblNyttUtstyr">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="UtlevertUtstyrID">UtstyrsID</th>
                <th data-field="UtstyrNavn">Navn</th>
                <th data-field="Utlevert">Utlevert</th>
                <th data-field="Comment">Kommentar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Motorola defy+</td>
   <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Samsung SII</td>
   <td>true</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then I have this script

```
var test = $("#tblNyttUtstyr tbody tr").map(function () {
            var $row = $(this);

            return {
                UtlevertUtstyrID: $row.find(":nth-child(1)").text(),
                Comment: $row.find(":nth-child(2)").text()
            };
        }).get();

        $("#console").text("content: " + test);
```

The return value are like this: "content: [object],[object]"

Anyone know howto get the values, the text instead of just object

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do ? why are you using `map()` ?

Comment: [`.map()` returns a jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/map/). This is exactly what should be happening. [`$.map()` returns an array](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), but neither one will ever return a string.

Comment: For a start, your selector is `#tblNyttUtstyr tbody tr`, but there's nothing in the `tbody`...

Comment: Sorry.. There are things in body, I will add that code. The body are build dynamic using jQuery

Comment: I want to get a string/json with the content of the table using jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.map returns a jQuery object.

You need to use callbacks.

```
    function setConsole(obj) {
        $("#console").text("content: " + obj.Comment);
    }

    var test = $("#tblNyttUtstyr tbody tr").map(function () {
        var $row = $(this);

        setConsole( {
            UtlevertUtstyrID: $row.find(":nth-child(1)").text(),
            Comment: $row.find(":nth-child(2)").text()
        } );

    }).get();
```

---

Update: change the `setConsole` function to this:

```
function setConsole(obj) {
    var c = $("#console");
    c.text(c.text() + "content: " + obj.Comment);
}
```

Or else every new object will just be overwritten.

See my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/FrURX/

Comment: See the new code I added to my post, the content of <tbody>. Now I get some text at least, but I only get this in my console: "content: Samsung SII" in my example above. It only returns the last row

Comment: To clearify I little better, I'm going to post all the content of the table using ajax, and my search on google told me that this way was the best way. So my plans are to include this json string when I post the data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain and even create an example!!